# SetThreadDesktop: ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Why every time that code below is executed, [`SetThreadDesktop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setthreaddesktop) fails with the following message:

> ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

The new desktop is created with success, then mean that have a handle opened.

What's happening?

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

var
  _hDesk: HDESK;

begin
  try
    _hDesk := OpenDesktop('test', 0, True, GENERIC_ALL);

  if _hDesk = 0 then
    CreateDesktop('test', nil, nil, 0, GENERIC_ALL, nil);

  if not SetThreadDesktop(_hDesk) then
  begin
    Writeln(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CreateDesktop` returns a handle. You need to use that handle to switch your thread to the desktop.

```
_hDesk := CreateDesktop('test', nil, nil, 0, GENERIC_ALL, nil);
```

Also be sure to check if the function succeeds, see documentation for how.